# accessing elements of list in scheme

Tags: scheme

How do I change elements of list in Scheme.
I want a procedure to change the minimum elements of a list to another number, so

If I have a procedure called proc and I give it two arguments ( a list and a number), my procedure would work like this:
`(proc (list 1 2 3 1) 9)` returns `'(9 2 3 9)`. so 9 take the place of the minimum value(s) of the list. I know I can apply min to get the minimum value, but I don't know how to modify a single element of the list.

Since Scheme doesn't have variables to hold values, I thought about using either let or letrec, but I don't know which would be the difference between using let and letrec.

Comment: What do you mean, Scheme doesn't have variables?  It does, but you should use them sparingly.  Schemers prefer to return a new list with new content rather than change the contents of the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be split into two distinct tasks - getting the lowest value in the list, then replacing that value with our new value. We can get the lowest value by running the `sort` function on our list and sorting by least to greatest, then using `apply min` to get the first element of the list.

After we've got that, we can use `map` to go through the list, replacing any instances of the lowest number with our new number. All in all, the complete function should look like this:

```
    (define (replace-least lst new)
      (let ((lowest (apply min lst)))
        (map (lambda (x) (if (= x lowest) new x)) lst)))
```

I tested this with DrRacket 5.3 and it performed perfectly as per the specifications provided in your question. If you have any trouble, let me know.

Comment: `(apply min lst)` can also be used to get the minimum.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my code to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: you need to get rid of the `car` too ;p

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved, *working* solution using `min`:

```
(define (replace-min lst elt)
  (let ((m (apply min lst)))
    (map (lambda (x) (if (= x m) elt x))
         lst)))
```

Notice that `min` is the simplest way to find the minimum element in a list.